# PythonでNoneが出る度にリセットしつつ、None以外の要素の出現数をカウントしたい

Tags: python

初心者です。Pythonで2次元リストの各リスト内の0.1.2.3番目をそれぞれNoneが出るまで何回連続で続いたか、またNoneが出たらリセットのプログラミングを教えていただきたいです。

入力：

```py
listA = [[0, -1, 1, 0],
         [1, 0, -1, 1],
         [0, 1, None, 1],
         [-1, None, 0, 1]]
```

出力：

```py
[4, 0, 1, 4]
```

このようにリスト内の0番は4回連続で続いたので4、1番目は4行目にNoneが出たのでリセットで0、2番目は3行目にNoneが出たのでリセットされて1、3番目はNoneがでず4回連続なので4というように出力したいです。よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 1番目が「リセットで0」2番目は「リセットされて1」というのが不明です。リセットとは？

Comment: 途中でも良いのでご自身で書かれたコードがあれば質問に追記してください。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
>>> [i[::-1].index(None) if None in i else len(i) for i in zip(*listA)]
[4, 0, 1, 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

数値を求めるところを関数で記述し，縦に（列で）調べる部分をリスト内包表記で記述してみました。

```
listA = [[ 0, -1, 1, 0],
         [ 1, 0, -1, 1],
         [ 0, 1, None, 1],
         [-1, None, 0, 1]]

def cnt(lst):
    n = 0
    for v in lst:
        n = 0 if v is None else n + 1
    return n

result = [cnt([listA[i][j] for i in range(len(listA))])
          for j in range(len(listA[0]))]

print(result)
```

```
[4, 0, 1, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

- 先頭から末尾までカウントする
- `None` が出る度にカウントを `0` にリセットする

というのを逆に考えると、

- 末尾から先頭方向へカウントしていく
- `0` が出たらカウントを中止する

となります。後者は `0` が出て以降のカウントを省略できる分だけアルゴリズムとしては効率が良いはずです。これを書くと例えば下のようになります。

```py
listA = [[0, -1, 1, 0],
         [1, 0, -1, 1],
         [0, 1, None, 1],
         [-1, None, 0, 1]]

width = len(listA[0])
height = len(listA)

result = [0] * width

# 0 から (width - 1) までカウントアップ
for w in range(width):
    # (height - 1) から 0 までカウントダウン
    for h in range(height - 1, -1, -1):
        # None が出たら現在のカウントを止める
        if listA[h][w] == None:
            break
        result[w] += 1

print(f"{result=}")
```